# Deleting picture files by looping through anonymous type

Tags: c#, asp.net, anonymous-types

I'm trying to delete physical photo files from Server by retrieving the virtual path using LINQ to SQL anonymous type but is has failed to work. I am using ASP.NET 4.5 and Entity-framework 5. Below is my code:

```
        //deleting all image gallery file collection
        using (ProductModelEntities DB = new ProductModelEntities())
        {

            var picsDB = from pk in DB.Pictures
                            where pk.MainId == _id
                            select new
                            {
                                pk.ImageUrl
                            };

            foreach (var picUrl in picsDB)
            {
                string fileNme = Server.MapPath(picUrl.ToString());
                System.IO.File.Delete(fileNme);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Failed because...?  This is basic debugging.  Step though it - does it find the urls?  Does it get the correct file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object is not just the URL, it's an object that has a property named `ImageUrl` that contains the URL. You need to get the URL from the property:

```
string fileNme = Server.MapPath(picUrl.ImageUrl);
```